# Member only page

Tags: php, authentication

I need help trying to make a member only page...so you can only get on it if you are logged in at login.php

This is the "login.php" page

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    global $connection; 

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $safe_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);

    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '{$safe_username}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
        $set_password = $row['password'];
        $input_password = $password;

        if($input_password == $set_password) {
            header("Location: home.php");

    die();
        } else {
            header("Location: logfailed.html");
            die();
        }
    } else {
            header("Location: logfailed.html");
            die();
    }
}
?>
```

This is the page I want to make member only "home.php":

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Congregate | Where Family Meets
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body bgcolor="grey">
    <center>
    <h1>Time Till This Website Goes Live:</h1>
    <span id="countdown"></span>
    <script>
        // set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Mar 26, 2014").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

// do some time calculations
days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

// format countdown string + set tag value
countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
+ minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

}, 1000);
    </script>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to enclose all of the next in blockquotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must store the information that user is logged into the session :

```
if($input_password == $set_password) {
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    header("Location: home.php");
    die();
}
```

Then, in any page that requires users to be logged in (home.php), you check `$_SESSION['logged_in']`:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || $_SESSION['logged_in'] !== true)
    header("Location: index.php");
```

Also do not forget to add `session_start();` in your login.php and home.php pages (and any other pages that requires authentication)

Answer (score 0):

How about this site which walks you through it;
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

or this;

http://www.php-login.net/